# access to column in python like awk

Tags: python, scripts, awk

This is my data file:

```
Iam
python
newbie
```

If I use **awk** to access columns element, that is easy just by **$1**. how can I access this columns element on python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, `awk` strips leading and trailing spaces and assigns each non-whitespace token to a field (if you do not change the field separator). This can be done in Python with:

```
import sys

f = sys.stdin
# If you need to open a file instead:
#f = open('your.file')
for line in f:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    # Array indices start at 0 unlike AWK
    print(fields[0])
```

Comment: work like a charm

Comment: where is array declaration  :) I think that way they love python

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, a name is not bound to a type. By the way, the return value is a tuple, not a list ("array"). If your input always have three fields for example, then you could use this: `field1, field2, field3 = line.strip().split()` and access `field1`, etc. directly.

Comment: no need to `strip()` as `split()` automatically strips every field